# Bluetooth keyboard suddenly won't pair anymore

Tags: keyboard, imac, bluetooth

I recently switched to an iMac14,2 and wanted to use my Microsoft Surface Ergonomic Keyboard with it.
Initially the keyboard paired fine and showed up with the correct name. After around two weeks of usage (several reboots and sleeps) the keyboard suddenly stopped working today. After waking up, it did continue to work for some time and then from one moment to the other it was gone from the bluetooth menu. I tried repairing it, but it now only shows up with its MAC address (?) and not the real name. When I hit pair it will try for some time and then just give up.

Here is what I tried already:

- several reboots, sleep/wakeup
- delete bluetooth.plist(s), reboot
- remove all bluetooth devices and reset bluetooth module, reboot
- reset NVRAM
- disable SIP (read that somewhere)
- swap keyboard batteries

My Magic Trackpad 2 and my headphones still work fine. My other (non-ergonomic) Surface Keyboard shows up with its correct name but won't pair either.

I understand that the keyboard may not officially support macOS, but it did work fine and I didn't change anything, so I don't know what could be wrong.

Edit: I should mention that I can re-pair the keyboard fine under windows.

Edit2: I am on Catalina 10.15.4 btw.
Maybe I'll try a fresh install on a second volume tomorrow and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Perhaps the last sentence should read: "... that macOS may not officially support the keyboard ... ." Are there any other BT enabled devices in the immediate area other than the Trackpad and headphones? Have you powered down the Trackpad and headphones as a test to see if they're interfering with the MSEK?

Comment: @IconDaemon yes, I just did that, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It seems like that towards the end of the pairing time window of the keyboard, it will suddenly show up as "Ergonomic Keyboard". When I try to pair it then, it still won't work and the LED stops flashing.

Comment: I installed a fresh copy of catalina on a second volume today and there the keyboard pairs fine. When I create a new user on my regular volume it again doesn't work, so there is something wrong with the installation. I tried to monitor all changes of files during the pairing process on the new install and deleted all those file in my regular install to be able to start fresh, but it didn't help.